# I am trying to scrape a website for links and also scrape the links inside the already scraped links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am trying to **scrape** a website for links and after scraping, I also want to see if the links that I scraped are just article or contain more links and if they do, I want to **scrape** those links as well. I am trying to implement it using BeautifulSoup 4 and this is what I have as code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ='https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/'
try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for post in soup.find_all(['h3', 'li'], class_=['entry-title td-module-title', 'menu-item']):
        link = post.find('a').get('href')
        print(link)
        r = requests.get(link, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        for post1 in soup1.find_all('h3', class_='entry-title td-module-title'):
            link1 = post1.find('a').get('href')
            print(link1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I want the links on the page *https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/* and **scrape** for possible links inside the links that I get from that page for example *https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/news/*, I want the links inside *https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/news/* as well. So far, I am only getting the links from the main page only.

Comment: So what is the current output when you run your code? Does it not manage to find the links on the page?

Comment: It doesn't give the links inside the link as I wanted.

Comment: @dspencer if I print  *post1* then I can see the links inside the link but if I try to get the 'href' attribute inside the <a> element, it doesn't print.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `raise e` from your `except` clause and you will see that the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

arises from the line `link1 = post1.find('a').get('href')`, where `post1.find('a')` returns `None` - this is because at least one of the HTML `h3` elements you retrieve does not have an `a` element - in fact, it looks like the link is commented out in the HTML.

Instead, you should split this `post1.find('a').get('href')` call into two steps and check whether the element returned by `post1.find('a')` is not `None` before trying to get the `'href'` attribute, i.e.:

```
for post1 in soup1.find_all('h3', class_='entry-title td-module-title'):                                                     
    element = post1.find('a')                                           
    if element is not None:                                             
        link1 = element.get('href')                                     
        print(link1)
```

Output from running your code with this change:

```
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/this-virus-doesnt-have-borders-port-official-warns-of-pandemics-future-economic-impact/
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/pharmacy-and-grocery-store-workers-call-for-increased-protections-against-covid-19/
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/up-close-and-personal-grooming-businesses-struggle-in-times-of-social-distancing/
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel-long-beach-secures-contract-for-new-major-convention/
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/hospitals-prepare-for-influx-of-coronavirus-patients-officials-worry-it-wont-be-enough/
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/portside-keeping-up-with-the-port-of-long-beach-18/
https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/news/
...
```